# Availability of firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore#reliability_and_performance) indicates that firebase realtime databases are limited to zonal availability in a single region. Does this mean that the data is replicated across multiple zones within a region? Can it withstand failure of a zone completely?

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

The Firebase Realtime Database is not replicated across zones, regions or locations. If that is a requirement for your use-case, I'd recommend you check out Google Cloud Firestore.

Comment: Did you mean Google Cloud Firestore?

Comment: Is the data replicated within a zone - can it withstand instance / node failures?

Comment: Woops, that was indeed meant to be Firestore. Fixed.